# LDAP proxy to AD always get invalid credentials

Tags: active-directory, proxy, ldap, raspbian

I'm trying to configure LDAP proxy to our ActiveDirectory server and I always get error when I'm trying to test if it works:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

I'm using RaspberryPI with raspbian installed to do it.

My *slapd.conf* file looks like below:

```
# Schema and objectClass definitions
include         /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/ad.schema

# Where the pid file is put. The init.d script
# will not stop the server if you change this.
pidfile         /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
# List of arguments that were passed to the server
argsfile        /var/run/slapd/slapd.args

# Support both LDAPv2 and LDAPv3
allow           bind_v2

# Read slapd.conf(5) for possible values
# logfile               /var/log/slapd.log
loglevel        256


# Where the dynamically loaded modules are stored
modulepath      /usr/lib/ldap
moduleload      back_ldap
moduleload      rwm

### Database definition (Proxy to AD)   #########################################
database                ldap
readonly                yes
protocol-version        3
rebind-as-user          yes
uri                     "ldap://192.168.1.247:389"
suffix                  "dc=domain,dc=name"
chase-referrals         yes
idassert-bind           bindmethod=simple
                          binddn="CN=adminauthenticator,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=name"
                    credentials=xxxxxxxxxxx
                    mode=none
idassert-authzFrom      "*"
overlay                 rwm
rwm-map                 attribute       uid     sAMAccountName
rwm-map                 attribute       mail    proxyAddresses
```

Am I missing something or doing wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to AD with ldapsearch using the same credentials?

Comment: No, I can not. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but when I use something like this
`ldapsearch -H ldap://192.168.1.247 -x -b "OU=Uzytkownicy,DC=domain,DC=name" -v -LLL -D "CN=testdomeny,OU=Uzytkownicy,DC=domain,DC=name"  -W`
I get the same error.